# Python chat box whith Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to do a chat box with Tkinter, but for send the text I want to press on Return key and not to click on a button. When Ï run this code, I can wrote in the Entry section, but when I press the Return key, nothing append. Thanks for your help.
(Sorry for bad English)

```
from tkinter import *


window = Tk()


input_user = StringVar()
input_field = Entry(window, text=input_user)
input_field.pack()

def Enter_pressed(event):
    """Took the current string in the Entry field."""
    input_get = input_field.get()
    print(input_get)



frame = Frame(window, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind("<Return>", Enter_pressed)
frame.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What James Kent said. You may also want to clear the text after you hit `<Return>`, so put `input_user.set('')` after the `print` call in your callback function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are binding to the wrong widget, when you press the return key that event is sent to the entry widget not the frame, so change

```
frame.bind("<Return>", Enter_pressed)
```

to:

```
input_field.bind("<Return>", Enter_pressed)
```

and if you want to prevent other bindings from firing you can add

```
return "break"
```

to the end of your function

Comment: It's work :) Thank you very much James for the usefull and quick answer.